I can't seem to install Steam correctly on my Debian-based version of Linux. Any solutions?
I've tried every solution I can find. Any tips?

Hi! We can't know what goes wrong and what exactly you've tried from your post. Please extensively expand your question (by editing it! Please don't just post comments.) to add exactly what you've tried, what happened (and if that's not self-explanatory, how that is different from what you expected). Also "debian-based" is honestly not good enough a system description; the range of things that are "debian-based" is just too large.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here’s how to install the Steam package provided in the contrib repository hosted on Debian’s infrastructure, in Debian 12 and later:

edit /etc/apt/sources.list to enable contrib; the bookworm line should look something like (the URL might be different)
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main contrib

update apt’s caches
sudo apt-get update

install Steam
sudo apt-get install steam-installer


When run, Steam will update itself as necessary.

To the future reader: note that this works great on debian binary-compatible distros (debian itself, (I think) devuan, ), and others with only minor modifications to the packaging process). It wouldn't work on other "debian-based" systems (like, say, Ubuntu, Mint, Kali) in general.

@Marcus Debian derivatives typically provide the steam-installer packages in their own repo — Devuan, Kali, Ubuntu do, and Mint then makes it available from the Ubuntu repos (or will, it’s in Noble).
